# How to setup source with cloud build java api?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Looks like the `gcloud` command line does a lot of things by default when I run:

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE_ID
```

for example it uploads the repo to GCS and then when the build starts it downloads it to the working directory.

I want to use the java api instead of invoking `gcloud` from another process.

Can I do the same using the java api, without implementing it manually? I couldn't find any samples on how to use the cloud build java api.

Kotlin code of what I have so far:

```
val buildDockerStep = BuildStep.newBuilder()
  .setName("gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker")
  .addAllArgs(listOf("build", "-t", imageRepository, "."))

val build: Build = Build.newBuilder()
  // .setSource() ? does this need to happen manually?
  .addSteps(buildDockerStep)
  .build()

val request = CreateBuildRequest.newBuilder()
  .setBuild(build)
  .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
  .build()

val result = cloudBuildClient.createBuildAsync(request)
```

Comment: Where are your source files located? From the Java client reference, [`setSource()`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-build/latest/com.google.cloudbuild.v1.Build.Builder#com_google_cloudbuild_v1_Build_Builder_setSource_com_google_cloudbuild_v1_Source_) should be the location of your source files to build (either Cloud Source Repository or GCS). This is also shown in the REST API [docs](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/projects.builds#source).

Comment: at this point the source file is a Docker file and a couple of scripts which is on the same directory with the code I have above. Looks like I need to zip and upload this to GCS myself I want to build a `StorageSource`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying to your comment, you would [indeed need](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit) to zip your source files and upload them to GCS if you’d like to build a `StorageSource`. While there isn’t any sample code or examples for the Java API client out there, I pieced together this code from the [API reference](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-build/latest/). It builds a `StorageSource` using my bucket and the zipped source archives, and builds a new image to upload to my Artifact Registry.

```java
StorageSource.Builder gcsSource = StorageSource.newBuilder()
    .setBucket(bucketName)
    .setObject(objectName); //Name of the zipped archive in GCS 

Source.Builder buildSource = Source.newBuilder().setStorageSource(gcsSource);

Builder buildStep = BuildStep.newBuilder()
    .setName("gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker")
    .addAllArgs(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"build", "-t", imageDir, "."}));

Build testBuild = Build.newBuilder()
    .setSource(buildSource)
    .addSteps(buildStep)
    .addImages(imageDir) //Adds the image to Artifact Registry
    .build();

CreateBuildRequest req = CreateBuildRequest.newBuilder()
    .setBuild(testBuild)
    .setProjectId(projectId)
    .build();

Build res = CloudBuildClient.create().createBuildAsync(req).get();
```

Let me know if this worked for you, as I could not find any other samples out there of the Java client. I tested it and it worked fine on my end.